# Callback with Getx's Get.back method

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx, flutter-navigation

Good day everyone!

I would please like to know: What is the best way to get a callback when leaving a page while using Getx's Get.back()?

So far I have tried the WillPopScope widget and I have tried passing a function as an argument in the "result" parameter of the Get.back() method, but none worked. Maybe I just did something wrong?

At the end of the day what I would like to achieve is: Executing code when leaving the current page.

Thank you in advance for any help :)

Comment: Did u try run a function after Get.back()?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this will help you to pass data from second to first screen

```
Get.back(result: [
{"backValue": "one"}]);
```

Comment: This does seem best, thx. Do you know if you can pass a method in the "result" field? I tried and I didn't get any errors, but the method doesn't get called.

Comment: till i get you this will help you
 Get.back(result: MetodName());

  String MetodName() {
    return "Data";
  }

Comment: This worked, thank you! Interesting, because if you pass an anonymous function it doesn't work, but if you actually pass a defined function then it does work